# How to make the enemy only start pathfinding when player is within certian distance

Tags: unity, 2d, path-finding

Im using A* pathfinding and unity 2d. Also im very new and dont really know how to code well so if you can tell me the code it would be much appreciated. I figured out how to use A* but i dont want the enemy to constantly follow my player every where

Comment: Presumably you tried [searching for "Unity chase radius"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+chase+radius&ia=web) and working through some of the guides that this brings up? What did you try based on your research so far, and where are you stuck on an issue the existing guides don't explain?

Comment: I just dont know where to begin at all. Like would i create a separate script or edit the one that a* uses? I couldnt find anything too useful to me just because i dont really know how to code that well.